# Not able to access any mothod with the attribute [WebInvoke] in WCF Restful services

Tags: wcf, service, webinvoke

I am not able to access any method with the attribute `[webinvoke]` in a RESTful WCF service.

My code is like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "Post", UriTemplate = "Comosite/{composite}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(string composite);
```

On executing the above service I am getting an error message

> Method not allowed.

I tried many ways, by modifying the urltemplate, method name and method type etc. but nothing is working out.

But if I use the `[WebGet]` attribute the the service method is working fine.

Can anybody suggest me what can I do make it work?

Thanks in advance... :)

Comment: the thing is i want to perform post/put/delete operation. using get i can get the date from the service ,but the thing is i just dont want to get the data, i want to  perform update and delete operations on the data. for that i was testing with webinvoke and post method. if post method works fine then i can proceed for delete and put methods.

Comment: Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb472541(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Can you show some of the code you have used to call your service?

Comment: I used HTTPClient object to communicate with the service. and it is working fine for Get method.

Comment: code for calling the service is as follows.

Comment: HttpClient http = new HttpClient("http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFRestService2/Service1/");
                                               
                string value;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a Input for Rest service2");
                value = Console.ReadLine();
                HttpResponseMessage resp = http.Post("Composite/" + value  , HttpContent.CreateEmpty());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "Post", UriTemplate = "Comosite/{composite}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
```

to

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Comosite/{composite}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a similar service as you have done here and called it with fiddler and that worked when I changed the method to POST all capital letters. When method is like Post as in your code I get an endpoint not found message.

My fiddler request looked like this:

```
http://localhost/service/service1.svc/Comosite/test
```

Here test is sent in as the composite parameter and I get a CompositeType as xml returned.